# Exercise on pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

Let $E$ a countable metric space then $E= \{x_n\}$, let $\{f_n\}$ a sequence of functions $f_n: E \to \mathbb{R}$, such that for every $x \in E$ exists $M_x$ s.t. $|f_n(x)|< M_x$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then exists a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ pointwise convergent.

I can't solve this exercise coud you suggest some references? 
Thank you!

Comment: what does 'pointwise limited' mean? Also, what are the codomains of each function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is immediate from 'Cantor's diagonal procedure'. There is a subsequence $(n^{(1)}_k)$ such that $f_{n^{(1)}_k}(x_1)$ converges. [ Because any bounded sequence in $\mathbb R$ has a convergent subsequence]. Now look at $f_{n^{(1)}_k}(x_2)$. There is a subsequence $(n^{(2)}_k)$ of $(n^{(1)}_k)$ such that $f_{n^{(2)}_k}(x_2)$ converges. Note that $f_{n^{(2)}_k}(x_1)$ also converges. Repeat this process. You get subsequences $(n^{(j)}_k), j=1,2,...$. Define $n_j$ to be $n^{(j)}_j$. This subseqeunce has the required property.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear to me why $f_{n_j^{(j)}}$ is pointwise convergent... it seems that only $f_{n_j^{(j)}}(x_i)$ with $i\leq j$ converges

Comment: For any fixed $i$ convergence of $(f_{n_j^{(j)}} (x_i)$ is convergent iff it is convergent after removing the first $i$ terms. Convergence of a  sequence is not altered by adding/deleting/modifying a few terms in the beginning of the sequence. @andres

Comment: Ok, it's clear thank you!